# intersection of Multidimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some  Multidimensional array like these：

```
a=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]
b=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]
```

I'd like to get their intersection in python . 
so I code 
       `c=[v for v in a if v in b]`

I want `[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]` but the code got wrong answer.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? Describe in detail how you want doublets handled.

Comment: set(a).intersection(b)   and   list(set(a) & set(b))  doesn't work

Comment: I 'd like the answer is [[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]

Comment: Yes, but why is `[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 12], [12, 6]]` wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code was that it was only checking whether an element of list `a` existed in list `b` regardless of **where** exactly or how many times. Try this:

```
a=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]
b=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]

from collections import Counter as cC

ac = cC([tuple(x) for x in a])
bc = cC([tuple(x) for x in b])
print(ac)
print(bc)
c = sorted([list(x) for x, v in (ac & bc).items() for _ in range(v)])
print(c)  # [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 12], [12, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reach if you remove from `b` an element that you already iterated, that way you append to `res` the minimum intersections of the same elements between `a` and `b`.

```
a=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]
b=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]

res = []
for _a in a:
  if _a in b:
    res.append(_a)
    b.remove(_a)

print (res)

>>> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 12], [12, 6]]
```

**EDIT:**

You can iterate through `a` and get the number of the element occurrences, do the same for `b` and extend the `res` list with the minimum between `occurence_count_a`  and `occurence_count_b`

Don't forget to check at the top whether the element is already in `res` list than, you don't need to extend it again as each iteration you can extend few elements to `res` (depends on the intersection between `a` and `b`) so when you get to a value that you iterated before, you don't need to worry about him as you extended `res` before with the minimum intersection of this element.

```
a=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]
b=[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 5],[5, 12],[12, 6]]

res = []
for _a in a:
  if _a not in res:
    occurence_count_a = a.count(_a)
    occurence_count_b = b.count(_a)
    res.extend ([_a for _ in range(min(occurence_count_a, occurence_count_b))])


print (res)

>>> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 12], [12, 6]]
```

Comment: ye,that's great .but i don't like remove,because it could make my data dirty.could u use anther function to help me.thx

Comment: @Ming , I've added an EDIT section to the answer.